# How to close HTML child page on button click in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have 2 pages login.html and register.html by clicking login.html button it will go to register.html and there I have register button by clicking this I wanna go to login.html and close the register.html page in my phone(its working but after this was done when I click button from login.html) again its getting enter into register.html.

I want to close or finish the register.html page. I stuck here, Please someone help...

Login.html :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


function onDeviceReady(){

}

    function signUp(){


    window.location="register.html";


    }

 <button onclick="signUp();">Sign Up</button>
```

Register.html :

```
   function register(){

   window.location="login.html";

   window.close();

   }

   <button onclick="signUp();">Sign Up</button>
```

where I making stupid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this

```
window.close();
```

Then try. If doesn't work

use this

```
document.location
```

instead of

```
window.location
```

**Update based on comment:**

in register.html, inside deviceready

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
```

And then

```
function onBackKeyDown_home()
{
    document.location="login.html";
}
```

Comment: Hai Atanu thanks for ur reply but its not working for me. Any other solution for this.

Comment: second function name is `register()`; then why second function call is `signup()` ? `<button onclick="signUp();">Sign Up</button>` in the register.html page @syedjibharat

Comment: sorry for that mistake I posted wrongly, but in my code I did correct.

Comment: <button onclick="register();">Register</button>

Comment: Its moving to next html page but its not getting closed, when I pressed back button the register.html will open. I don't want to open that page this time.

Comment: I'm using document.location for a long time, this should work. I can't think of any other way.

Comment: Wait! when you press the back button!! To control the behavior of the back button you need to override the back button. See my updated answer. @syedjibharat

Comment: I wanna to close that page while clicking the register button and at the same time it will go to login.html how this possible?

Comment: I done your updated code in login.html its working for login purpose but for other scenario it will be difficult to handle

Comment: You can wait to see if anyone has a better solution. And I'm not 100% sure what do you mean by 'closing the register page'. What I understood is that you're using multi-page architecture, register.html isn't any kind of popup, it's a page,so you'll need to redirect it when it's done(not close it).If you want it to be some kind of popup page,I think you'll need some kind of framework like jquery mobile etc.